For every finite group, does there exist a (finite) undirected graph with that automorphism group?
I know that the symmetric groups $S_n$ are the automorphism groups of the complete graphs $K_n$, and that the dihedral groups $D_{2n}$ are the automorphism groups of the cycle graphs $C_n$. In addition, I was able to manually construct graphs with some specific automorphism groups (for example, a graph with four vertices and one edge has $V$ as its automorphism group). But is it possible for all groups? That is,

For all groups $G$, does there exist at least one finite undirected graph $H$ such that $\text{Aut}(H) = G$?

If so, how do you prove it? If not, is there an explicit counterexample? Also, does the problem change at all if you instead consider directed graphs?

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/37356/realizing-groups-as-automorphism-groups-of-graphs

@testaccount I think it should be OK to post this as a community wiki answer to put this question off the unanswered list.

When asking for a finite graph, you surely want to assume that the group is finite?

@MartinBrandenburg Yes, that was my intention. Sorry for the confusion. (Edited accordingly.)
